# static constexpr char m_pszFoo[] = "***FOO***" has compile error expression did not evaluate constant

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

error code is C2131.

intelisense does not complain even when I call size of on this variable in other files intelisense knows the size. what am I missing to get this working? Any help is greatly appreciated. In the pic below see intelisense  not complaining and also determining size.

[image]

example a.h:

```
class a
{
private:
static constexpr char m_pszFoo[] = "***FOO***"; // compile error on this line C2131 expression did not evaluate to a constant

public:
a() { sizeof(m_pszFoo); }; // no compile error here
};
```

to reproduce all you need to do is include a.h in any other file. It won't reproduce without the include.

Comment: @NathanOliver verrified the above example in msvc 2015 14.0.24720.00 update 1

Comment: I can confirm it does not compile in MSVS.  Both clang and gcc compile.

Comment: try making the constructor `constexpr`

Comment: Hi @M.M constexpr causes another error for sizeof. "statement may not appear in a constexpr constructor." Is that what you expected? If so what does it prove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I came up with a work around b\c that error message made it seem like i needed to add a const somewhere

```
static constexpr char const m_pszFoo[] = "**FOO***";
```

for some reason if we tell the compiler that we should not be able to change  the char to which the string points msvc is happy.

*** Edit ***

I got some suggestions to file a bug with microsoft and let them investigate as this looks to be an interop bug with msvc.
here is the  connect.microsoft link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2781048